# Cannot store a Double value in Realm database in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I'm just trying to understand Realm and ran into an issue. I have a model like this

```
class Template: Object {
    dynamic var id = NSUUID().UUIDString
    var pages = List<TemplatePage>()
}
class TemplatePage : Object {
    var xPosition: Double = 0.0
    var yPosition: Double = 0.0
}
```

Now, I'm executing the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var templatePages = [TemplatePage]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addTemplatePage(1.0, yPosition: 2.0)

        //add more template pages
        //[...]
        //when all pages have been added create a template out of it.
        addTemplate()
        getXCoordinateOfFirstTemplatePage()


    }

    //Execute this method several times depending on the user interation
    //here we only execute it once
    func addTemplatePage(xPosition: Double, yPosition: Double) {

        do {
            let templatePage = TemplatePage()
            templatePage.xPosition = xPosition
            templatePage.yPosition = yPosition
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(templatePage)
            }

            templatePages.append(templatePage)
        }
        catch _ {
            print("error while adding a template page")
        }
    }
    //once all pages have been added create a template of of all recently added pages
    func addTemplate() {
        do {
            let template = Template()
            try realm.write {

                template.pages.appendContentsOf(templatePages)
                realm.add(template)
            }
        }
        catch _ {
            print("error while adding the template")
        }
    }    
    func getXCoordinateOfFirstTemplatePage() {
        let template = realm.objects(Template)[0]
        print(template.pages[0].xPosition)
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it prints 0.0, the default value of the TemplatePage xPosition property. However, I don't understand why because I would actually expect it to print 1.0. I don't quite get why. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced similar issues. Whenever you use nested class like you are doing with `TemplatePage` make the variables dynamic.

Change

```
var xPosition: Double = 0.0
var yPosition: Double = 0.0
```

to

```
dynamic var xPosition: Double = 0.0
dynamic var yPosition: Double = 0.0
```

Comment: Realm's documentation is quite clear on requiring `dynamic` for properties: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet

Answer (score 1):

I tried few things with 'RealmSwift' for Swift 4.2 to store Double value in Realm. The following worked well. @objc is for Swift version and also Realm does not allow me to define Double as Optional like Double? so I gave the default value.

```
@objc dynamic var height: Double = 0.0
```

Comment: Yeah, that was weird and took a while to figure out

Comment: @Mike Exactly. Have you find another solution ?